# MediaPlayer Stop code - Where to put?

Tags: java, android

On a fragment I have a selection of buttons which play sounds.

I have a ScrollView and a button in a LinearLayout which is stuck to the bottom of the screen.

I'm stuck on where to to enter the code that will ensure that on button press mediaplayer is stopped.

This is my SoundsFragment.java file that will be hosting the code, and my button is called         button_stop. I have already called a listener for this as you can see, I'm just unsure of where to place the mediaplayer stop code.

If you could edit this code or provide an example that would be brilliant so I can better understand java layout.

```
package /example/;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class SoundsFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    private static MediaPlayer mp = null;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sounds, container, false);
        Button button1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        Button button2=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        Button button_stop=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this); 
        button_stop.setOnClickListener(this); 

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
     int resId;
     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.button_1:
       resId = R.raw.a;
       break;
     case R.id.button_2:
        resId = R.raw.b;
       break;
     default:
       resId = R.raw.a;
       break;
     }
     // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
     if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
     }
     // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), resId);
     mp.setLooping(true);
     mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      if(null!=mp){
     mp.release();
      }
      super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to just create a different onClickListener for button_stop after you declare it:

```
button_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
```

I'm not certain if it will still call the default onClick() function. If so, you could create a separate function to call whenever a button other than button_stop is pressed:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 int resId;
 switch (v.getId()) {
 case R.id.button_1:
   startMediaPlayer(R.raw.a);
   break;
 case R.id.button_2:
   startMediaPlayer(R.raw.b);
   break;
 case R.id.button_stop:
   mp.stop();
   break;
 default:
   startMediaPlayer(R.raw.a);
   break;
 }

}

public void startMediaPlayer(int resId){
  // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
 if (mp != null) {
    mp.release();
 }
 // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), resId);
 mp.setLooping(true);
 mp.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler, the different onClickListener appears to be working exactly how it should! I couldn't work it out originally as creating a separate function using the same template as the other buttons doesn't work.